# Position: sticky in css grid?

Tags: css, css-position, css-grid, sticky

I have a "sticky" navigation bar that lives inside a css grid container. 
It is set so it sticks to the top of the viewport as soon as it reaches it.
That works fine.

But the css grid container is still the parent of that navigation bar, also when the "stickyness" kicks in. When we scroll further, the container (which is being scrolled out of the viewports) takes the navigation bar with it.

I guess that's the definition of `position:sticky`?

Maybe I should change the element to `position:fixed` when it reaches its place with js? It would have been nice to do it without JS. But then again, I have to change some other properties as background color etc.

PS: I hope it's ok I didn't include an example. It's more about the concept.

Comment: Sticky positioned elements works relative to it's parent's scroll, not the viewport. So yes, when the container goes out of sight then it takes with it the sticky element. You'll have to use JS if you want it to stay visible when the container goes out of view.

Comment: This is already the answer I needed, thanks!